# MSBuild Extension Pack Zip the folders and subfolders

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have to Zip my folders and subfolders Using MSbuild, I was looking at the MSBuild Extension pack, and tried this

```
 <ItemGroup>
  <ZipFiles Include="\Test\Web\**\*.*" >
    <Group>Release</Group>
  </ZipFiles>
 </ItemGroup>



 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip TaskAction="Create" CompressFiles="@(ZipFiles)" ZipFileName="$(WorkingDir)%(ZipFiles.Group).zip"/>
```

When I do this it just keep adding all the files to root, instead of adding it into the specific subfolder within the zip file.

I am missing something, can anyone help here please.

Answer (score 11):

You need to provide a `RemoveRoot` property, this property sets the root to remove from the compress files path. ([More info](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.4.0/html/a2a08495-b9e8-3e70-ee63-bcf033d61210.htm))

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ZipFiles Include="\Test\Web\**\*.*" >
    <Group>Release</Group>
  </ZipFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip 
                        TaskAction="Create" 
                        CompressFiles="@(ZipFiles)" 
                        ZipFileName="$(WorkingDir)%(ZipFiles.Group).zip"
                        RemoveRoot="\Test\Web"/>
```

Comment: FWIW, using $(TargetDir) for both ZipFiles Include and RemoveRoot will target the build output files and create a flat ZIP

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have a value for the RemoveRoot property.

Answer (score 0):

Since, nobody answered early, I went ahead and used 7 Zip, Command line utility, to do that.