# Adding files to a zip using MSBuild ExtensionPack Zip creates entire file structure

Tags: msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I'm looking at [`MSBuild.Extensionpack.Compression.Zip`](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/f2118b59-554e-d745-5859-126a82b1df81.htm) to add a custom build step where I'd like to add some files to an existing .zip archive.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Files Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder\*.xml">
  </Files>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="@(Files)"></Message>

<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip TaskAction="AddFiles" 
                        CompressFiles="@(Files)" ZipFileName="$(MyZipArchive)"/>
```

When running this, the files are indeed added to the zip archive, but not into the root. Instead it creates a file hierarchy that corresponds to the path of my project

```
Projects/MyProject/SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/myfile.xml
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the `myfile.xml` inside the root of the .zip archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I was getting to hasty. Just found the solution in [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906835/msbuild-extension-pack-zip-the-folders-and-subfolders?answertab=votes#tab-top).

The AddFiles action has an optional property `RemoveRoot`. Here you have to specify the string of the root you want to remove.

Final solution looks like this.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Files Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder\*.xml">
  </Files>
</ItemGroup>

<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip TaskAction="AddFiles" 
                        CompressFiles="@(Files)" ZipFileName="$(MyZipArchive)"
                        RemoveRoot=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder />
```